# Is there any way to select element through HTML, by selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium

I am making crawling app through selenium, python and I am stuck.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrsDS.jpg)

as in picture I can select text(with underline).
but what I need is numbers next to text.

but in F12 in chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIIi4.jpg)

numbers(red cricle) has class name, but that class names are all same. 
there is no indicator that I can use to select numbers through selenium.(as far as I know)

so I tried to find any way to select element through HTML by selenium.
but I couldn't find any. Is there any way to do?

If I am looking for something does not exist, I am very sorry. 
I only know python and selenium.. so If I cannot handle this, please let me know.

---edit

I think I make bad explanation. 
what I need is find text first, than collect numbers (both of two). 
but there is tons of text. I just screenshot little bit. 
so I can locate texts by it's specific ids(lot's of it). 
but how can I get numbers that is nest to text. 
this is my question. sorry for bad explanation

and if BeautifulSoup can handle this please let me know. Thanks for your help.

---

special thanks to Christine

her code solved my problem.

Comment: is necessary to use selenium ? ..can be BeautifulSoup?

Comment: get all elements and later use index - ie. `all_items[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an XPath index to accomplish selecting first `td` element. Given the screenshot, you can select the first `td` containing `2,.167` as such:

```
cell = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td/a[text()='TEXT']]/td[@class='txt-r'][1]")
print(cell.text)
```

You should replace `TEXT` with the characters you underlined in your screenshot -- I do not have this keyboard so I cannot type the text for you.

The above XPath will query on all table rows, pick the row with your desired text, then query on table cells with class `txt-r` within a row. Because the two `td` elements both have class `txt-r`, you only want to pick one of them, using an index indicated by `[1]`. The `[1]` will pick the first `td`, with text `2,167`.

Full sample as requested by the user:

```
# first get all text on the page
all_text_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'link-resource')]")

# iterate text elements and print both numbers that are next to text
for text_element in all_text_elements:

    # get the text from web element
    text = text_element.text

    # find the first number next to it (2,167 from sample HTML)
    first_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td/a[text()='" + text + "']]/td[@class='txt-r'][1]")
    print(first_number.text)

    # find 2nd number (0 from sample HTML)
    second_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td/a[text()='" + text + "']]/td[@class='txt-r'][2]")
    print(second_number.text)
```

Comment: For the _all rows_ case, you may like to replace `cells = driver.find_element` with `cells = driver.find_elements`

Comment: Correct :) I had missed the extra `find_elements` while pasting the line from previous sample.

Comment: I think I make bad explanation. what I need is find text first, than collect numbers (both of two). but there is tons of text. I just screenshot little bit. so I can locate texts by it's specific ids(lot's of it). but how can I get numbers that is beside text. this is my question. sorry for bad explanation

Comment: @Shineuichul Updated my answer based on the new information.